# Sum Programme adding square of numbers

Tags: java

college assignment here and need to do the following:

1. The sum of all numbers divisible by 13 between 1 and 100 inclusive
2. The sum of all numbers squared between 1 and 100 inclusive

The output i get when adding the squared numbers is 338714 but correct answer is 338350 - can someone advise where exactly i am going wrong

```
public class Summing {
public static void main (String args []){
int sum = 0;
int n = 1;
int square;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
if (i%13==0)
{
sum = sum + i;
}
}
System.out.print("The sum of all all the numbers is divisible by 13" = sum);

while (n<=100){
square (n*n);
sum = sum + square;
n++;
}
System.out.print("The sum of all the numbers squares is " + sum );
}
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger and watch the variables.  Perhaps `sum` needs to be reset before starting the second loop?

Comment: Unrelated: Going forward, please get in the habit of indenting your code. It will make it much easier on yourself as well as anybody trying to help.

Comment: Unrelated: not sure what compiler application you are using. But if that prevents from getting your code as text via copy/paste, then: consider using another tool. To work with java, you only need to install a JDK and a text editor. Sure, that is a bit of learning, too. But learning how to manually write your files, name them correctly, place them in the correct directory, compile and run them. That is all essential knowledge of Java.

Comment: And note: in programming details matter. Always properly indent your source code. You are not indenting your loops blocks... Which makes it really hard for anybody to read your input. Please spend the 1 minute it takes to indent properly before submitting your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

338714 - 338350 = 314 which is exactly the sum of your first mission :)
You hav to reset "sum" variable, because when getting into the second loop its value is 314 which is the difference.

Comment: Thanks so much - i wont tell you how many hours ive been at that scratching my head!  Thanks so much